# How to pass by value XML Groovy nodes to a variable

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to duplicate te result of this instruction:

```
 def xmlEntrada = new File("input.txt").text
    def entrada = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlEntrada)

        def usuarios = entrada.cust_PS_SF_compensation.findAll{ e-> e.cust_userId.toString() == codigoActual }
        def usuariosWithEndDate = entrada.cust_PS_SF_compensation.findAll{ e-> e.cust_userId.toString() == codigoActual }
```

but all the nodes of the variable usuariosWithEndDate are with the same reference and i need a copy by value of this operation result for edit in parallel.

usuariosWithEndDate is an arrayList with a different reference repect to usuarios but the content (the nodes) have the same reference, help please[image]

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to show the sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, we want `clone()` here.

Given this XML:

```
<entrada>
<cust_PS_SF_compensation>
    <cust_userId>5150</cust_userId>
</cust_PS_SF_compensation>
<cust_PS_SF_compensation>
    <cust_userId>6160</cust_userId>
</cust_PS_SF_compensation>
<cust_PS_SF_compensation>
    <cust_userId>7170</cust_userId>
</cust_PS_SF_compensation>
</entrada>
```

Here is the Groovy code with `assert` statements acting as a form of specification (if I understand the question):

```
def xmlEntrada = new File("input.xml").text
def entrada = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlEntrada)
def codigoActual = "5150"

def usuarios = entrada.cust_PS_SF_compensation.findAll{ e ->
    e.cust_userId.text() == codigoActual 
}
assert 1 == usuarios.size()

def usuariosWithEndDate = entrada.cust_PS_SF_compensation.findAll{ e -> 
    e.cust_userId.text() == codigoActual 
}.collect { node ->
    node.clone()
}

assert 1 == usuariosWithEndDate.size()

assert ! usuarios[0].is(usuariosWithEndDate[0])
assert codigoActual == usuarios[0].cust_userId.text()
assert codigoActual == usuariosWithEndDate[0].cust_userId.text()
```

Comment: Nice !!, the solution was .collect { node ->
    node.clone()
}